# jtable.org jQuery Jump to index? Customize paging?

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

I'm just getting started with jtable. Looks very useful! Thanks. I'm struggling to see how I can use the public API to do two things:

1. I've got a search form that permits a user to search for a particular row. I'd like to be able to programmatically "jump" to that row. Is it possible? Is there a suggested approach?
2. I'd like to customize the paging controls to give context to the pages (e.g., use result ranges rather than page numbers to guide the user). Is there a recommended approach for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jTable sources are available on GitHub: `https://github.com/hikalkan/jtable`, so you will be able to find everything you need.

For example:

- for your 1st point, you may use filtering if you can, as it is already available: `http://jtable.org/Demo/Filtering`
- for your 2nd point (custom paging), take a closer look to `https://github.com/hikalkan/jtable/blob/master/dev/jquery.jtable.paging.js`: the build of the table footer is made in this file for example.

It will be a bit long, but you have the keys to modify the behaviour and implement it the way you want.